Create 3d plot in tikz respecting 3d position
I am drawing different planes in a 3d plot and I want the order in the figure (i.e., which planes are in front of other planes) to respect the 3d position and not the order in which the code is written. The planes are either vertical (in gray in the figure below) or horizontal (in colors in the figure below).
The code is generated programmatically in a script depending on input data: hence it is not possible to manually change the order of the code.
The following code generates a simple example:
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[view={-30}{60},
        samples=2,zmin=0]
        \addplot3[fill=white!70!gray] coordinates {(134.5, 10, 9)(165.0, 10, 9)(165.0, 10, 0)(134.5, 10, 0)(134.5, 10, 9)} ;
        \addplot3[fill=white!70!gray] coordinates {(71.5, 10, 2.5)(134.5, 10, 2.5)(134.5, 10, 0)(71.5, 10, 0)(71.5, 10, 2.5)} ;
        \addplot3[fill=white!70!gray] coordinates {(0.0, 10, 1.7)(71.5, 10, 1.7)(71.5, 10, 0)(0.0, 10, 0)(0.0, 10, 1.7)} ;
        \addplot3[fill=white!70!gray] coordinates {(86.0, 3.3, 7)(134.5, 3.3, 7)(134.5, 3.3, 2.5)(86.0, 3.3, 2.5)(86.0, 3.3, 7)} ;
        \addplot3[fill=white!70!gray] coordinates {(71.5, 3.3, 3)(86.0, 3.3, 3)(86.0, 3.3, 2.5)(71.5, 3.3, 2.5)(71.5, 3.3, 3)} ;
        \addplot3[fill=white!70!gray] coordinates {(134.5, 0.0, 0)(165.0, 0.0, 0)(165.0, 0.0, 9)(134.5, 0.0, 9)(134.5, 0.0, 0)} ;
        \addplot3[fill=white!70!gray] coordinates {(86.0, 0.0, 0)(134.5, 0.0, 0)(134.5, 0.0, 7)(86.0, 0.0, 7)(86.0, 0.0, 0)} ;
        \addplot3[fill=white!70!gray] coordinates {(71.5, 0.0, 0)(86.0, 0.0, 0)(86.0, 0.0, 3)(71.5, 0.0, 3)(71.5, 0.0, 0)} ;
        \addplot3[fill=white!70!gray] coordinates {(0.0, 0.0, 0)(71.5, 0.0, 0)(71.5, 0.0, 1.7)(0.0, 0.0, 1.7)(0.0, 0.0, 0)} ;
        \addplot3[fill=white!70!gray] coordinates {(165.0, 0.0, 9)(165.0, 10, 9)(165.0, 10, 9)(165.0, 0.0, 9)(165.0, 0.0, 9)} ;
        \addplot3[fill=white!70!gray] coordinates {(134.5, 3.3, 2.5)(134.5, 10, 2.5)(134.5, 10, 9)(134.5, 3.3, 9)(134.5, 3.3, 2.5)} ;
        \addplot3[fill=white!70!gray] coordinates {(134.5, 0.0, 7)(134.5, 3.3, 7)(134.5, 3.3, 9)(134.5, 0.0, 9)(134.5, 0.0, 7)} ;
        \addplot3[fill=white!70!gray] coordinates {(86.0, 0.0, 3)(86.0, 3.3, 3)(86.0, 3.3, 7)(86.0, 0.0, 7)(86.0, 0.0, 3)} ;
        \addplot3[fill=white!70!gray] coordinates {(71.5, 3.3, 1.7)(71.5, 10, 1.7)(71.5, 10, 2.5)(71.5, 3.3, 2.5)(71.5, 3.3, 1.7)} ;
        \addplot3[fill=white!70!gray] coordinates {(71.5, 0.0, 1.7)(71.5, 3.3, 1.7)(71.5, 3.3, 3)(71.5, 0.0, 3)(71.5, 0.0, 1.7)} ;
        \addplot3[fill=white!70!gray] coordinates {(0.0, 0.0, 0)(0.0, 10, 0)(0.0, 10, 1.7)(0.0, 0.0, 1.7)(0.0, 0.0, 0)} ;
        \addplot3[surf,shader=interp,opacity=1,fill opacity=1,domain=0.0:71.5,domain y=0.0:10]{1.7};
        \addplot3[surf,shader=interp,opacity=1,fill opacity=1,domain=71.5:134.5,domain y=3.3:10]{2.5};
        \addplot3[surf,shader=interp,opacity=1,fill opacity=1,domain=71.5:86.0,domain y=0.0:3.3]{3};
        \addplot3[surf,shader=interp,opacity=1,fill opacity=1,domain=86.0:134.5,domain y=0.0:3.3]{7};
        \addplot3[surf,shader=interp,opacity=1,fill opacity=1,domain=134.5:165.0,domain y=0.0:10]{9};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


However, the desired output would instead be

According to this question: Plot TikZ items with respect to 3D position, not the order of appearance in the code, it is not possible to achieve this with tikz, but would be possible with Sketch, is that correct (I would prefer not to use Sketch)? If it is not possible to achieve in tikz, is there a simple algorithm based on coordinates I can implement myself to figure out the order of the addplot3 commands?

Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please explain the differences between the two images? I do not see one...

Thanks! Sorry, should perhaps have chosen a more obvious example. See the orange plance connecting to the green/gray plane (and also the green/gray plane connecting to the blue one, though that is more subtle.

So the code is produced by a script that you can not change! The best way I see is to write an other script the post processes the code. That would best be done in something that is not LaTeX. e.g. perl or python.

No, certainly I can change the script (which indeed is written in python). However, I don't know how to figure out which planes should be in front of others.

Are the planes representing boxes/bars?

Not necessarily, but if it makes it easier I can work with boxes. So no slanted planes.

You can draw things behind other things using layers. But (1) I have no idea how (or if) that applies to pgfplots and (2) you still have to figure out the order and tell TikZ which layer to draw what on. But TikZ doesn't have any concept of 3d. It's a 2d programme, so if you want stuff to look 3d, you have to tell it how to fake that ;). Does gnuplot know 3d? You can use that to do calculations for pgf/tikz, so if it knows 3d, it might be able to help with the fakery. (But I have NO idea whether it does or not.)

gnuplot knows 3d. You could let it do the calculations and then use the results in pgf/tikz.

thanks, I'll have to look in to gnuplot then.
